# Woocommerce Calculate make a calculation

Tags: cart

I have a question.
I have two types of taxes.
If I have a product in cart with tax A (10%) I have to calculate in cart 10% on total cart of this quantity x price; if I have a product with rate B (4%) I have to calculate 4% on total cart of this quantity x price; if I both I have to make the product and then the addition.
How Can I make?
Thanks a lot

Comment: global $woocommerce;
$key = $tax->tax_rate_id;
$tax_name = wc_get_tax_class_by_tax_id( $key );
if ($tax_name == "zero-rate") 
$tax_rate= 10; 
else $tax_rate= 4;                      
$with_tax = $woocommerce->cart->total; 
$without_tax = $with_tax/((100+$tax_rate)/100);
$tax = $with_tax-$without_tax;
$tax2 = $tax*$tax_rate/100;
$tax3 = $tax+$tax2;
$tax3 = number_format($tax3, 2, '.', '')." €";
echo "  ".$tax3." (".$tax_rate."%)";
$tot = $with_tax + $tax3;
$tot = number_format($tot, 2, '.', '')." €";
echo "<br>";
echo $tot;

Comment: This code is ok if the product is tax rate or not.